# How to delete everything in a string after a specific character follow by numbers?

Tags: unix, sed

I have this file:

```
Cavr.NG178.1       Cavr.NG12780.1_at      APTG386_at-255
Cavr.NG056.1       Cavr.NG02560.1_at      APTG560_at-895
Cavr.NG714.1       Cavr.NG77140.1_at      APTG680_s_at-2732
```

I would like to delete everything after "at-" of the last column, for example:

```
Cavr.NG178.1       Cavr.NG12780.1_at      APTG386_at
Cavr.NG056.1       Cavr.NG02560.1_at      APTG560_at
Cavr.NG714.1       Cavr.NG77140.1_at      APTG680_s_at
```

But the codes that I tried are also affecting the second column, for example:

```
sed 's/at-*//'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(.*at).*/\1/' file
```

Output:

```
Cavr.NG178.1       Cavr.NG12780.1_at      APTG386_at
Cavr.NG056.1       Cavr.NG02560.1_at      APTG560_at
Cavr.NG714.1       Cavr.NG77140.1_at      APTG680_s_at
```

Answer (score 2):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/_at[^[:space:]]*$/_at/' file
```

The output:

```
Cavr.NG178.1       Cavr.NG12780.1_at      APTG386_at
Cavr.NG056.1       Cavr.NG02560.1_at      APTG560_at
Cavr.NG714.1       Cavr.NG77140.1_at      APTG680_s_at
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/-[^-]*$//' file
Cavr.NG178.1       Cavr.NG12780.1_at      APTG386_at
Cavr.NG056.1       Cavr.NG02560.1_at      APTG560_at
Cavr.NG714.1       Cavr.NG77140.1_at      APTG680_s_at
```

or:

```
$ cut -d- -f1 file
Cavr.NG178.1       Cavr.NG12780.1_at      APTG386_at
Cavr.NG056.1       Cavr.NG02560.1_at      APTG560_at
Cavr.NG714.1       Cavr.NG77140.1_at      APTG680_s_at
```